# How to check if a user is logged in with spring-security?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've implemented ajax login/logout in my client code against a backend running spring-security.

What I need to know is how to tell whether or not the user is logged in.

For instance:

- User logs in. This returns a 200 from the POST to /login. I could set some variable to track state on the client side.
- User refreshes browser. Now the state is lost.

So, I want to know if there's some way from the client to check whether or not the user is authenticated and logged in purely from the client.

Is there such a way?

Comment: does the back-end will spit out 401 HTTP Status code (Forbidden/Access Denied) if user try to access service without login first? Usually ajax use HTTP Status Code to identify if the request is success or not

Comment: It does. It returns a 401 when the user is not authenticated.

Comment: Then every ajax request that gets 401 can be considered that the user need to login. You can delegate it to a handler that will pop out or redirect to login page. So you don't have to maintain the state in the client.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Super slick actually. Good call Mang!

Answer (score 4):

In JSP, you can access request user prinicial (or) use spring security taglib to get authenticated user roles

Example: Access request user principal in JSP

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
    <label>
     Hi ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} ! Welcome to our site
    </label>
</c:if>
```

Example:
A variable isAuthenticated depending on granted roles for user logged in.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <sec:authorize access="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')" var="isAuthenticated">
    </sec:authorize>

    <c:out value="${isAuthenticated}"/>
```

Even you can enable/disable some html using the same tag

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <a href="delete/${file.id}">Delete</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

If you want to get from javascript, then you need to expose a backend method returning request.userPrincipal

Comment: Thank you Anudeep. I'm working in Javascript. I ended up setting up GET against /login to return the username. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

What I actually did was add an endpoint to respond to `GET /login`. It returns a 200 with the username in the response body when the user is logged in with a valid session. When the user is not logged in or has an invalid session the response returns a 401 (and no response body).

I then have handlers in the javascript code that bring up a login modal when it receives the 401 and does nothing when it receives the 200.

Works beautifully :)