# Redirecting to home page after login in HTML with spring security

Tags: javascript, html, spring-security

I am trying to login and redirect request to home page. In my current state I am able to login successfully but viewing the blank page. I don't want to use redirect strategy in spring/server side. My HTML login page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/login.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring security config:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole(new String[] { "ADMIN" }).and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").permitAll();
```

I want to do some fixes in HTML itself in order to redirect request to home page on success and on login page itself on failure. How I can do this? I searched much but did't found a perfect solution, it will be good if someone post the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an endpoint to [check if the user is logged in][1].

You can then write an javascript function to call that endpoint and redirect when the user is authenticated. Call the function from `<body onload="yourfunction()">`

[1] [How to check if a user is logged in with spring-security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448749/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-with-spring-security)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify a custom `successHandler` like this

```
http.formLogin()
  .loginPage("/login.html")
  .successHandler(myCustomSuccessHandler);
```

In your successHandler you can redirect to any url you want.

See the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)

Comment: Again that success handler is server side change. Which I don't want to do.

Comment: A custom redirect in html can only be done through javascript. But you'll be fighting the framework which won't make it more secure.

Comment: Yes! I am interested in that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the job using angular js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="loginapp" ng-controller="loginctrl"> 
<form ng-submit="login();">
    <input type="text" ng-model="username" required>
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</div>
<script>
var loginapp = angular.module('loginapp', []);
loginapp.controller('loginctrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.login = function(){$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/login.html?username='+$scope.username+'&password='+$scope.password,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function(response){$scope.user=response.data;$window.location.href= '/';});};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```